# Trouble tunneling my local Wordpress install to the mysql database on appfog

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp, appfog

I've set up a wordpress install on appfog (using rackspace), and cloned the install to my local machine for development. I know the install works (using MAMP) because I created a local mysql database and changed wp-config.php to point to it. However, I want to develop without having to change wp-config.php every time I commit. After doing some research, it seems like the Appfog service Caldecott lets me tunnel into the mysql database on the server, using `af tunnel`. Unfortunately, I'm having issues with getting it working. Even if I change my MAMP mysql port to something like 8889, and tunnel mysql through port 3306, it looks like it's connected but I still get "Error establishing a database connection" when loading my localhost Wordpress. When I quit the mysql monitor (using `ctrl+x, ctrl+c`), I get a message stating "Error: 'mysql' execution failed; is it in your $PATH?'. Originally, no, it wasn't, but I've fixed my PATH variable on my local machine so that when I go to Terminal and just type `mysql`, it loads up.

So I guess my question is 2 parts:

1.)Am I going with the right approach for Wordpress development on my local machine

and
 
2.)If so, why is the tunnel not working?

Comment: Well I haven't met a CMS that everyone likes, and we're starting Drupal at work, so I want to get experience with wordpress too.

Comment: @davidkonrad I agree, however there are so many 3rd party plugins that it's worth a shot to learn. I wish it were written in RoR though.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with this is to mimic the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable on your local system with your local database settings. This would allow you to use the same custom AppFog [wp-config.php](https://github.com/appfog/af-php-wordpress/blob/master/wp-config.php) file which looks at VCAP_SERVICES to get its db creds.

```
export VCAP_SERVICES='{"mysql-5.1": [{"credentials": {                      
    "hostname": "localhost",          
    "port": 3306,            
    "password": "root",            
    "name": "LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME",            
    "user": "root"}}]}'
```

EDIT: You will need to restart the Apache server in MAMP after setting this env var. (Thanks Dex)

This will eliminate the need to point your development code at your production database.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to make the MAMP GUI recognize the VCAP_SERVICES var. So after it starts up I manually call `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -k stop && /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -k start` from a terminal

Comment: Also, by default for MAMP, hostname should be `localhost` and user/pass are both `root`.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what this does? Does it tell the local database to copy content from the one on the server? (You mean by `LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME` that I have to create an empty db on my local machine to route through, right?) How can I check what my `VCAP_SERVICES` variable has saved in it? When I do something like `emacs VCAP_SERVICES`, nothing seems to be in there.

Comment: No this would not copy the database from the server. You have to create a local database and configure LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME with the db name. The local db would just be for testing locally before updating your production app. You could copy your production db and import it locally if you want to have sample data to develop with.  To check your local VCAP_SERVICES var use the cmd: `echo $VCAP_SERVICES`. if you have not exported anything yet you should get empty string.

Comment: You can use the phpMyAdmin (PMA) jumpstart AF offers and then bind your wordpress database to it. Then use PMA to export the database.

Answer (score 1):

simply test for whether vcap_services are available. if they are, use one config. if they arent, use a different config.

here is an example of my local + appfog development website configuration file.

> 

```
if(getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")){
    //if in webserver
    $services_json = json_decode(getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"),true);
    $mysql_config = $services_json["mysql-5.1"][0]["credentials"];
    $username = $mysql_config["username"];
    $password = $mysql_config["password"];
    $hostname = $mysql_config["hostname"];
    $port = $mysql_config["port"];
    $db = $mysql_config["name"];

    define("DB_SERVER", "$hostname");
    define("DB_USER", "$username");//enter your database username
    define("DB_PASS", "$password");//databse password
    define("DB_NAME", "$db");//database name
} else {
     //if in local development
     define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
     define("DB_USER", "website");//enter your database username
     define("DB_PASS", "dfgdfgdf");//databse password
     define("DB_NAME", "fgdf_web");//database name
}
```

also, you can use .afignore same way you'd use .gitignore to ignore some files from the af update feature. u can update once with appropriate config, then add afignore, then it will never get updated again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and *very* dirty script to automate the process based on Tim Santeford's answer. Be sure to change the LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME

```
#!/bin/bash

export VCAP_SERVICES='{"mysql-5.1": [{"credentials": {"hostname": "localhost", "port": 8889, "password": "root", "name": "LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME", "user": "root"}}]}'

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -k stop

sleep 3

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -k start
```